# Dyadic squares intersection

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to do the following exercise from Pugh: prove that any two dyadic squares of the same size are either identical or intersect only along their edges.

I think I am not being able to read it in a suitable way because I think $A=[0,1]^2$ and $B=[1/2,3/2]\times [-1/2,1/2]$ would be a counterexample to that assertion.

Comment: What is the definition of a _dyadic square_?

Comment: When you speak about Pugh, dont you think a reference would be welcome ? The more a question is self-contained, the more likely you will have answers...